# Where is the folder with color schemes used by vim?

Tags: unix, settings, color, vi

I use vi on mac os x at work and on Ubuntu at home. I like the colorscheme vim uses on the mac and I'd like to copy the corresponding file on ubuntu, but I can't find it, since there's no ~/.vim folder.
Searching on the web I always find the answer "create it", but this is not the point, since I just want to see (and copy) an already installed colorscheme.

Comment: I think they're located in $HOME/.vim/colors/ and you enable the one you want by editing $HOME/.vimrc file with "colorschemes name_of_scheme" (no quotations)

Comment: As I already wrote, there's no directory with this name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4396772/5825294): color scheme's and syntax' files can be found in `/usr/share/vim/`.

Answer (score 3):

You should install new ones into

```
$HOME/.vim/colors/
```

you can run

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/colors
```

to create it.

Comment: This is absolutely not what OP asked for.

Comment: Would you share what need to be install? "colorscheme" from Vim, https://vimcolorschemes.com/?

Answer (score 1):

in macOS v 12.1 (Monterey) you can use below to list all available color schemes

```
ls -l /usr/share/vim/vim*/colors/
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, in Vim,

```
:h :colo
```

leads to (reformatting applied):

> `colo[rscheme] {name}` Load color scheme `{name}`.  This searches `'runtimepath'`  for the file `"colors/{name}.vim"`.

and you can jump to the help for `runtimepath` with `CTRL-]` or

```
:h runtimepath
```

But this will tell you only the defaults. To view the actual, current `runtimepath`:

```
:set runtimepath
```

or

```
:set rtp
```